# 3D models: converting from binary file, learning to read hex dumps

Tags: 3d, binaryfiles, hexdump

I have a 3D object stored in an unknown binary format. I opened it in a hex editor and noticed that the first line said "OBJF", followed by some lines that were translated as material and texture names. So at least I'm convinced it's a 3D object.

Now I need to figure out the vertices and normals and UV's and maybe other information, but I have no clue how to figure that out. So I will need to learn how to read hex dumps somewhat effectively before trying to guess at what the data might represent.

Where should I start?

Comment: Seems like it. Someone asked me to convert it, but didn't give me any details. Maybe I could just grab a free format and try to work with that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's a regular old OBJ file, but with triangle steps included.  More info at this link: http://file-extension.paretologic.com/detail.php/File-Extension-objf

Answer (score 0):

I think this talk may be of interest for you:

http://events.ccc.de/congress/2008/Fahrplan/events/2942.en.html